# Error :: duplicate files during packaging of APK in Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

In my project I use jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar libraries . After running application in android studio i got this Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/ASL2.0
    File1: F:\Projects\Cordova\AdapterProject\platforms\android\libs\jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
    File2: F:\Projects\Cordova\AdapterProject\platforms\android\libs\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
```

my code :

CordovaLib:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar'
    exclude 'libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
```

and
Build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar'
    exclude 'libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
```

How can I fix the problem

**Note**: I use these libraries in android Project(Not cordova) but it works and i don't have  problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

cordova 1.x.x any version library used when i worked on Phone gap application, so i think,if you are working on phone gap then it necessary to import file in your project otherwise ignore this library 
so error may be due to CASE -SENSITIVE 
so delete this NOTICE.txt from packagingOptions

Comment: i create android plugin with cordova but i need to using some libraries

Comment: brother.try using in exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt' and exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.TXT'

Comment: it's not work.if you see above my code, i wrote that's code

Comment: did you try NOTICE.txt instead of using notice.txt .means remove notice.txt and other dublicate files from list..try it then definatly will be solved..remove all duplicate

Comment: did you get output?

Comment: i delete NOTICE.txt in the another jar file and it's worked for me. thank you @harsh

Comment: you welcome.then click to accept my  answer after click to accept